# Convert all the properties of a List<Class> to a datatable in ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq, datatable

Following are my classes and function to convert a `List<Class>` to datatable.

```
public class Designation
{
    #region Variables
    string _ValueField;
    string _TextField;
    #endregion

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (!Factory.ISValidString(_ValueField)) ? null : _ValueField.Trim();
        }
        set
        {
            _ValueField = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (!Factory.ISValidString(_TextField)) ? null : _TextField.Trim();
        }
        set
        {
            _TextField = value.Trim();
        }
    }
}

public class Designations
{
    public Designation NewDesignation { get; set; }
    public Designation OldDesignation { get; set; }
    public Designation ProposedDesignation { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a function which can convert a `List<Designation>` to a datatable. It is as follows.

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

But this function doesn't work on my `List<Designations>`, what modifications should I do so that this function works on `List<Designations>`.

When i call this function with `List<Designations>`, I am getting the following table columns as output.

```
NewDesignation
OldDesignation
ProposedDesignation
```

I am expecting the following output.

```
NewDesignation.Value
NewDesignation.Text
OldDesignation.Value
OldDesignation.Text
ProposedDesignation.Value
ProposedDesignation.Text
```

Comment: You say it *doesn't work* but you don't say *how* it's not working. What output are you getting vs what you are expecting?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: `NewDesignation.Value` Your `ToDataTable` looks at properties of `Designations`. It doesn't look at properties **of** properties.

Comment: Yaa true, Is there a way to specify my function to drill down to all the properties in a class

Comment: Look at what `ToDataTable` does. See how it uses reflection to get the properties of `Designations`? Use that same technique **again** to get the properties **of** properties.

Comment: this may be unrelated, but: *why* do you want to put the data into a `DataTable`? `DataTable` is almost always the *least preferable mechanism* of storing data; well, perhaps it is better than an `object[][]`, but... that's probably the closest competitor. A specific class and `List<T>` is usually preferable **in every way**

Comment: I want to put it in a datatable to apply a filter on any of the properties like  NewDesignation.Value in ('SROFF','VPHEAD'), and then bind it to gridview.